# Top element is drawing amps but no hot water drawing 19amp

Tags: electrical, water-heater

I have 240v at the water heater and drawing 19amp at the top element but no hot water after 1 hour

Comment: Are you sure you are measuring the current correctly. You are saying that the water heater is consuming  more than 4.5 kilowatts and is not heating the water. Then where is that power going? Something must be heating up.

Answer (score 4):

### Check to make sure that water's getting to the bottom of the heater

If an electric water heater is drawing nameplate power but not appreciably heating water, then one of two things is wrong.  Either the *dip tube* in the heater has broken off internally, causing water to "short circuit" past the heating elements, or the heater was plumbed backwards with cold water trying to enter via the exit port and hot water exiting via the dip tube, which will cause similar symptoms as you're then drawing from the coldest water in the tank.

Comment: Make sure the T&P valve  isn't stuck open.

Comment: @JACK -- I'd figure they'd have noticed by now if the T&P was spewing water all over the floor :)

Comment: Mine's piped to the outside. All the homes down here are done the same way. :-)

Comment: All that heat has to be going *somewhere*.